# Auto fill textbox (username) in a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I would like to redirect to a website login page from my html page. I have the email id and I need to set the same as userid in the website. I need to fill it while redirecting, so that the user just need to enter only password.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your application already knows which user it is, why then have a username textbox in the first place? Couldn't you just ask the user for his password?

Comment: @Flater : Thanks for your reply. I want to redirect to a different website (https://www.dropbox.com) from my html page. I have user mail id and while redirecting to dropbox site, i want to set the same email.

Comment: You're asking for your page to actually run its code on the next page? Can't be done. Unless Dropbox has allowed for you to use querystring parameters, but that is something you have to ask Dropbox (if such information exists). In general, this is not possible unless the developer of that website implemented an option for you to use.

Comment: ok. Is it possible to set the value using client side scripting like jquery or javascript?

Comment: Only if you are the developer of the Dropbox website. How would you feel if anyone could start running their code on your webpage? (I didn't mean that to sound so offended. Just think what would happen if anyone could run any code on any website. Madness would ensue). The only thing you can do, after the dropbox page has loaded, is use the console. But that'd be manual labor, and more difficult than entring your username.

Comment: I dont want to control their website. Only thing is I will redirect to their website from my page. Using href tag or something like that. But at the same time I need to pass the mail id from my page and the same should set in their website. Can we achieve it passing the value as querystring or assign the value using jquery or something like that?

Comment: **Querystring**: only if the developer of Dropbox added a specific custom snippet of code that fills in the username if a specific querystring parameter is passed. How to find out? Ask Dropbox (or check their FAQ/wiki if they have any) **jQuery**: As mentioned before, no. Technically speaking, you could do it via the Console in your Web Developer Toolbar (Chrome/FF/...), but it'd be a manual task the end user has to perform, and considerably more difficult than actually entering the username. **Secondly**: Is this not a problem that solves itself if the enduser's browser stores his form input?

Answer (score 0):

Please do post some code at least let us know which programming language are you using...?

Normally this can be solved by:

```
<?php
  $blablabla = $_GET['username'];
?>

Username: <?php echo $blablabla ?>
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply. I want to redirect to a different website (dropbox.com) from my html page. I have user mail id and while redirecting to dropbox site, i want to set the same email. I need to achieve the same using HTML and jQuery.

Comment: @Sanoop Hey is too crazy for me I guess... You don't even own Dropbox.com and you don't even know what's the name and id for the USERNAME input field... If you done that, please come back and let me know as I'm interested at this question as well...

Comment: This is the control. We have id and name.
<input autofocus="1" tabindex="1" type="email" name="login_email" id="login_email">

Answer (score 0):

The below is my final answer in the comment thread below the question.

**Querystring**: `only if the developer of Dropbox added a specific custom snippet of code that fills in the username if a specific querystring parameter is passed. How to find out? Ask Dropbox (or check their FAQ/wiki if they have any). Personally, I doubt it. But that's just an experienced guess.`

**jQuery**: `As mentioned before, no. Technically speaking, you could do it via the Console in your Web Developer Toolbar (Chrome/FF/...), but it'd be a manual task the end user has to perform, and considerably more difficult than actually entering the username. This technically adheres to your question, but goes way out of scope in regards to complexity and pointlessness of the task.`

**Secondly**: `Is this not a problem that solves itself if the enduser's browser stores his form input? They'd only have to enter it once (IF the browser doesn't already suggest their email address from the first try, which is what Chrome and FF like to do (from personal experience)).`

What you want to achieve is not possible. However, the problem you are trying to solve is relatively trivial, as the problem is already almost completely circumvented by having your endusers' browsers store entered form values.